# Storing a three.js scene in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, three.js

Is there a simple way to keep a three.js scene within a mongodb collection; so that I can edit the scenes in a local database and save it to a server? I'm using meteor.

Comment: What to you mean by "a simple" way? In fact the problem boils down to how well you can serialize your data. Since THREE.js can load/save models in JSON format you're good to go but still you will have to play around things like storing large assets like geometry (meshes) for example. Turns out Meteor is not really efficient in loading large mongo documents which may make the things a little more complicated. I suggest deferring large assets to static files and only put object data into MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks I'm fairly new to all of this web stuff I can program 3d stuff but Don't know much about the web development .. I guess that I should use three.js to create my scene lights, camera  etc,  I want the user to be able to edit objects. eg; put tables and chairs of varying sizes and relative positions in the scene, using parameters defined on a form. I am thinking now that I should just keep track of the parameters and then write my own functions to create the three.js objects

Comment: I'm using three.js pretty extensively in my meteor app, and pretty much exactly what @apendua said. It's easy to store references to geometry and texture files where needed.

Comment: I disagree, indeed since a threejs scene is like a json tree you can easily store data in mongoDB. But there is no problem to use it with meteor since you can ask it to load only one entry, so it behaves like any other framework asking one file to the database.

Comment: Thankyou for the comments, I've come to the conclusion that I should write my code for  creating objects based on parameters. Store the parameters in my mongo collection. And create the scene with objects as required. I'm going to put a few more specific related questions up on here shortly. Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 1):

Using meteor this is the default behaviour i.e. you change locally and the result is saved into the server.

Now as a scene could be quite large, you will very likely need to update the json not as whole but using key path `Scenes.update("sceneid", {"$set":"some.path":"value"});`

You might also consider having a scene editor as a [json editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor) or something more advanced understanding the three.js syntax. If so, assuming you know AngularJS, I would recommend using AngularJS on top of Meteor, use any of the graphical [json tree editor](http://krispo.github.io/json-tree/) (or your own editor), simply bind the scene to the scope using `$scope.myScene = $scope.$meteorObject(Scenes, sceneid);`, add a [ThreeJS renderer](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/02/mixing-angularjs-threejs/) and you are done.

Within a page of code you will have a graphical json tree editor, able to edit any json document (this one being your scene) and synchronised with your server's db. I.e. every little change on the json structure will be applied locally but also sent to the server and modify the MongoDB scene entry.